# XCUIApplication large launchEnviroment causes launch failure

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9, xctest

When attempting to launch an application from the UITest module with a large launch environment string, for some reason the application gets stuck loading and starting opening the closing the app over and over. I'm curious if anyone else has has this issue. Here is some example code:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchEnvironment["my-key"] = "really long string"
app.launch() <-- this line open and closes the app loads of times, but never fully completes
```

When commenting the large string out, everything loads fine. Does anyone know why this might be?